# Why am I measured against points?

Tags: society

Why are we suddenly in a didgital 'social' heirachy..where my questions and answers are based on how I PLEASE u! Why do i want to stay in a world like this?

Comment: If you would like help in formatting your questions, please visit the meta site and we will be happy to help. (https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your question is not about worldbuilding as defined in the [help], if you have an existential question then [philosophy.se] is the forum to look at, or a question about the nature of what is on-topic here, then you'd want to look at [meta.se].

Comment: Based on your previous question, I would recommend trying to ask your questions on Philosophy instead of here. Just remember that you are asking other people, to help answer a question for free. They are taking the time to read and address your problem. You should take the time to create a well thought out question.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot answer why you would want to stay on a website like this. When it comes to technical questions, like the original [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) boards, I **really** appreciate that good answers are moved up.

And looking at sites like [Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions), deleting trolls is a necessity to keep the site from being overrun by garbage. And instead of having the *commercial company* offering the site [moderate](https://stackoverflow.com/company) things, they are calling on experienced users who were up**voted** by the community to pitch in.

Comment: So i being assumed 2 be a troll because I bruise some precious egos..do u gno me, have u met me in person? NO.

Comment: @corequality, read what I wrote. I talked about the need for moderation and the need to rank answers. I didn't talk about any specific thing you did in what I wrote. I voted to hold your previous question, because I thought it was *off topic*. I don't know you, but I know two of your questions and I judged *those*.

Comment: @corequality, in a nutshell, we are a board dedicated to the building of consistent fictional worlds. Your previous question had a somewhat promising headline, apart from spelling and punctuation, followed by a text which does not match the headline. One could build interesting questions around "how does a culture look where stealing is not wrong" and also "how would a culture look where stealing is wrong and defined more broadly than in real life." In either case, one would have to define the starting point -- do people in the real world suddenly wake up and change their morals? (cont.)

Comment: @corequality, (cont.) Or did this change happen before the start of the capitalist/industrial era, leading to a different pattern of industrialization and economic development? Completely different ballgames. My guesstimate is that a civilization where *stealing is not wrong* would be unable to progress much beyond the iron age, because more development requires collective efforts based on a rule of law or at least a ruler who keeps order. It could be an interesting basis for a fantasy novel or a game, but not a good place to live in.

Comment: @corequality, if the change happened to the modern world as we know it, there would be a breakdown of civilization because our economy depends on property and contracts. Again there could be an interesting adventure setting, except that the sudden change would be harder to explain. Starting somewhere in prehistory, or at least in early history, would be easier to tell coherently.